# Argument passing in Restful webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

In SOAP i use the following code to pass argument to a webmethod function

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "replacinginstrumentname")
    public String replacinginstrumentname(@WebParam(name = "interface1_name") String interface1_name)
```

Where interface1_name is the argument i pass. SOAP has @webparam for this sake.

But how can i do the same in Restful GET method.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are to ways to go:

(1) http://your.service.com/service/interface?interface1_name=YOUR_VALUE

or

(2) http://your.service.com/service/interface/YOUR_VALUE

Then your resource method would be

for case (1)

```
@Path("/service")
public class YourResource{

    @GET("/interface")
    public Response method(@QueryParam(name="interface1_name") String param){
        //do the job
    }
}
```

for case (2)

```
@Path("/service")
public class YourResource{
    @GET("/interface/{iname}")
    public Response method(@PathParam(name="iname") String param){
        //do the job
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying mate, as i can see from your example above, you pass the value in the URL, isn't it? But is it possible to pass the argument in the function itself? so that he function could take the argument and perform the operation and return back the result.

Comment: Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanx a ton in advance.

Comment: Not really, whole fuss about REST is to pass everything in HTTP request; there is also one more possibilty to insert data into HTTP request body as a XML or JSON and then the resource function have as an argument Java class and the incoming JSON is transformed to this class' object. However in a given situation that would be overkill I think.